# Spray rejections is not converted to status code?

Tags: scala, spray, spray-dsl

I am following spray manual from [here](http://spray.io/documentation/1.2.2/spray-routing/security-directives/authenticate/#http-basic-authentication). So I put to gather pretty simple test

```
class AtoImportServiceApiTest extends WordSpecLike with MustMatchers with ScalatestRouteTest {

  "AtoImportService" must {
    "return HTTP status 401 Unauhorized when accessing withou basic auth" in {
      Post("/ato/v1/orders/updateStatus") ~>new AtoImportServiceApi().route ~> check {
        handled must be(false)
        rejections must have size 1
        status === StatusCodes.Unauthorized
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am calling route which contains authorized directive. So I would expect that rejection will get transformed to HTTP status code. But that is not happening here and test is failing.

```
Request was rejected with List(AuthenticationFailedRejection(CredentialsMissing,List(WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="bd ato import api")))
ScalaTestFailureLocation: spray.testkit.RouteTest$class at (RouteTest.scala:74)
org.scalatest.exceptions.TestFailedException: Request was rejected with List(AuthenticationFailedRejection(CredentialsMissing,List(WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="bd ato import api")))
    at spray.testkit.ScalatestInterface$class.failTest(ScalatestInterface.scala:25)
```

Am I missing some important concept here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to "seal the route" to see actual status codes. Sealing the route means that the default rejection and exception handlers are used to handle any so far unhandled rejections and exceptions. This automatically done when using `runRoute` in your service but it isn't done automatically in the testkit to allow you to check for rejections directly.

Using spray-testkit you need to wrap your route with `sealRoute(...)` as explained here: http://spray.io/documentation/1.2.2/spray-testkit/#sealing-routes

Try this:

```
Post("/ato/v1/orders/updateStatus") ~> sealRoute(new AtoImportServiceApi().route) ~> check { // ...
```